# Importing function of a module in python

Tags: python

Below are 3 modules,

`point.py`  `segment.py`  `rectangle.py`,

where `rectangle.py` module imports a function object from `segment.py` module as mentioned,

`from segment import get_size`.

```
# point.py
# Representation - start
from operator import sub, mul
from math import sqrt
#Constructor
def make_point(x, y):
    return (x, y)

#Selector
def x_coordinate(point):
    return point[0]

#Selector
def y_coordinate(point):
    return point[1]

#Selector
def distance_between_points(p1, p2):
    return sqrt(square(sub(p1[0],p2[0])) + square(sub(p1[1],p2[1])))

#helper for selector
def square(a):
    return mul(a, a)

#Representation - end

#Use - start

def get_x_coordinate(point):
    return x_coordinate(point)

def get_y_coordinate(point):
    return y_coordinate(point)

#Use - end
```

---

```
# segment.py
# Representation - start

from point import distance_between_points, make_point, get_x_coordinate, get_y_coordinate
#Constructor
def make_segment(point1, point2):
    return (point1, point2)

#Selector
def start_segment(lineSegment):
    return lineSegment[0]

#Selector
def end_segment(lineSegment):
    return lineSegment[1]

#Representation - end

#Use -start
def midpoint_segment(lineSegment):
    return make_point((get_x_coordinate(start_segment(lineSegment)) + get_x_coordinate(end_segment(lineSegment)))/2, (get_y_coordinate(start_segment(lineSegment)) + get_y_coordinate(end_segment(lineSegment)))/2)

def get_size(lineSegment):
    return distance_between_points(start_segment(lineSegment), end_segment(lineSegment))

#Use - end


#Driver code from user
p1 = make_point(1,2)
p2 = make_point(3, 4)
line = make_segment(p1, p2)
midpoint = midpoint_segment(line)
print(midpoint)
```

---

```
# rectangle.py
# Representation - start
from point import make_point, get_x_coordinate, get_y_coordinate
from segment import get_size
from operator import sub, abs
#Constructor
def make_rectangle(p1, p2, p3, p4):
    if are_opposite_sides_equal(p1, p2, p3, p4):
        return (p1, p2, p3, p4)

#Helper for constructor
def are_opposite_sides_equal(p1, p2, p3, p4):
    if (abs(sub(get_x_coordinate(p1), get_x_coordinate(p2))) == abs(sub(get_x_coordinate(p3), get_x_coordinate(p4)))) and (abs(sub(get_y_coordinate(p2), get_y_coordinate(p3))) == abs(sub(get_y_coordinate(p1), get_y_coordinate(p4)))):
        return True
    else:
        return False

#Selector
def get_length_side_segment(quadruple):
    return (quadruple[0], quadruple[1])

#Selector
def get_breadth_side_segment(quadruple):
    return (quadruple[1], quadruple[2])

#Representation - end


#Use -start
def perimeter(rectangle):
    segment1 = get_length_side_segment(rectangle)
    segment2 = get_breadth_side_segment(rectangle)
    length = get_size(segment1)
    breadth = get_size(segment2)
    return 2 * (length + breadth)

def area(rectangle):
    segment1 = get_length_side_segment(rectangle)
    segment2 = get_breadth_side_segment(rectangle)
    length = get_size(segment1)
    breadth = get_size(segment2)
    return (length * breadth)

#Use - end



#Driver code from user
p1 = make_point(1, 1)
p2 = make_point(3, 1)
p3 = make_point(3, 3)
p4 = make_point(1, 3)
rectangle = make_rectangle(p1, p2, p3, p4)
peri = perimeter(rectangle)
area_value = area(rectangle)

print(peri)
print(area_value)
```

---

My question:

As per the debugging of `rectangle.py`, 
line `from segment import get_size` makes the driver code of `segment.py` execute and give the output `(2.0, 3.0)`.

I am using this statement to get access to `get_size`. I would like to understand, How an import of function object would give this output?

Comment: When you import a module it executes the statements in it.

Comment: @PeterWood  when I say, `from segment import get_size` Am I importing just a function `get_size` of module `segment` or the complete module `segment`? Because I do not have access to other functions of module `segment` in module `rectangle`

Comment: If you do not want that code executed, you should put it under `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 2):

Importing modules in python basically means you execute them as a script. This happens in both cases, even if you say `import foo` or `from foo import bar`. Python needs to run `foo` to be able to find the function `bar`.

In the first case (`import foo`) you have access to the full namespace, i.e. you could use `foo.getsize()` or `foo.bar()` or whatever functions, objects or whatnots your module provides. Whereas in the latter case (`from foo import bar`) you import only the function `bar` into your current namespace, i.e. you could only use `bar()`, but not `getsize()`, for example.

Furthermore, there is a simple way to make python execute parts of a module if and only if it is run as the main module and **not** if it is imported. For instance, in `segment.py`, you could write the following at the end of the script:

```
def main()
    #Driver code from user
    p1 = make_point(1,2)
    p2 = make_point(3, 4)
    line = make_segment(p1, p2)
    midpoint = midpoint_segment(line)
    print(midpoint)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

First of all, we define a `main` function. This `main` function is **only** called if the statement `__name__ == '__main__'` is `True`. What does this mean? Well, `__name__` is an inherent variable of the module itself. Every time the module is run via `python segment.py` or imported via `import segment` or via `from segment import something`, this variable is set differently.

If you run the module via `python segment.py`, `__name__` is equal to the string `'__main__'`. If you import the module, `__name__` is set to the name of the module, here `'segment'`. Thus, you can easily distinguish if a module is run as a main file or just imported by another file.

---

*EDIT:*

More on why does `from foo import bar` needs to fully execute `foo`!?

If Python did not execute `foo`, how should Python know that the module contains the function `bar`? Python is an interpreted language, so functions and other objects are really only created from source during runtime.

However, Python is smart enough to execute your script only **once**. Thus, several other imports of `foo` - even in other scripts - do not require re-executing your module, because the namespace of *foo* is already established. This behaviour has some advantages in terms of giving you freedom to modify any module/package (also from other people) during runtime. So if you know what you are doing, you can monkey-patch functions and objects of any imported module. These modifications can affect the whole scope of your program (including all other modules and scripts importing the modified library). 
Note that this is often dangerous but from time to time incredibly helpful.

Anyhow, [THIS](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) might also be a useful read.

*/EDIT*.

Answer (score 0):

by doing `from something import somethingelse` you still import `something` and then just add `somethingelse` to your namespace so the `something` module does get processed meaning your top level code will get run hence you are getting the output from print

if you don't want that don't have any module level code that is not a class or function declaration

Comment: what is the difference between  `import segment`  and `from segment import get_size`?

Comment: @overexchange the former will give you the name `segment` to use, the later will give you the name `get_size` to use. Both however will execute the `segment` module if it is the first time it has been imported by your system.

Comment: @PeterWood "Both however will execute"? this is not convincing syntax.Because it is breaking the purpose because am saying  `import get_size`  but not `import segment`

Comment: But how should python know that your module actually contains a function called `get_size` if it does not execute the script? Python cannot partially execute `segment.py` only containing the function you need. Think about it, what would happen in the case your function `get_size` actually depends on many other functions in `segment.py`?

Comment: @SmCaterpillar That is an abstraction that python should provide python programmer. I should not care about it. I tried to understand like  `import pkg1.pkg2.class3` in java. I learnt that python is also compiled to intermediate state(byte code) and then interpreted

Comment: @overexchange the difference between those two is just semantics, under the hood python still processes full module and creates all the objects for functions in your module - with the only difference being that in `from` case it only adds specific function to your namespace. But import will always process full module and will execute all the code (top level) in it.

Comment: @overexchange You are saying you want to use things from the `segment` module. Python will load that module into memory and execute it. This defines any functions, variables, classes, etc, and also calls any other statements in the top level of the module. Then the functions, etc, will be available to you to import. If you want the whole module you say `import segment` if you only want `segment.get_size`, and don't want to have to call it as `segment.get_size()` you can give it a local name `from segment import get_size`. This lets you call it as `get_size()`.

Comment: @PeterWood  When you say python will load that module into memory, the functions/variables/classes will not get into active module's global frame, until you import them?

Comment: @overexchange if you say `import segment` only `segment` will be added to your local module variable. You can then only access the functions by referring to `segment`, e.g. `segment.get_size()`